# Python struct unpack and negative numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, struct, binary

I'm using `struct.unpack('>h', ...)` to unpack some 16-bit signed numbers that I'm receiving from some hardware over a serial link.

It turns out whoever made the hardware hasn't heart of 2's complement number representation and to represent a negative number, they just flip the MSB.

Does `struct` have a way of decoding these numbers?  Or do I have to do the bit manipulations myself?

Comment: Looking at the documentation, I'd almost say that it's something you have to do yourself ...

Comment: If you use `'>H'` instead of `'>h'`, it shouldn't be too hard to do ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comments, the documentation does not mention such a possibility. However, if you want to do the conversion by hand, it is not too difficult. Here a short example how to do it using `numpy` arrays:

```
import numpy as np

def hw2complement(numbers):
    mask = 0x8000
    return (
        ((mask&(~numbers))>>15)*(numbers&(~mask)) +
        ((mask&numbers)>>15)*(~(numbers&(~mask))+1)
    )


#some positive numbers
positives  = np.array([1, 7, 42, 83], dtype=np.uint16)
print ('positives =', positives)

#generating negative numbers with the technique of your hardware:
mask = 0x8000
hw_negatives = positives+mask
print('hw_negatives =', hw_negatives)

#converting both the positive and negative numbers to the
#complement number representation
print ('positives    ->', hw2complement(positives))
print ('hw_negatives ->',hw2complement(hw_negatives))
```

The output of this example is:

```
positives = [ 1  7 42 83]
hw_negatives = [32769 32775 32810 32851]
positives    -> [ 1  7 42 83]
hw_negatives -> [ -1  -7 -42 -83]
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
hexstring = "c2280000"
#should be -42

print(struct.unpack(">f", struct.pack('>L', int("0x"+hexstring, 16)))[0])

Answer found from Masahif:
https://gist.github.com/masahif/418953